# What is total cost on renting room for vacation?

Tags: american-english

I am read about a room for vacation but I am not understand here:

"Additional fees are not calculated automatically in the total cost and will have to be paid for separately during your stay."

Why it say "additional cost not calculated" but it says it is "total cost"? It's wrong?

I think total cost mean everything. ?

http://www.booking.com/hotel/us/town-house-motel.en-us.html?aid=398636;sid=f1b9ae011ed2984c4da2efb0294ed1c7;dcid=4;src=clp;openedLpRecProp=1

Answer (score 3):

It means that the "total cost" which you will be quoted and charged immediately upon booking only covers the facilities and amenities named. It does not include any additional fees you may incur - for instance, charges for late check-out, or the charge for additional adults and older children which appears a couple of lines above this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This reminder usually refers to

Additional fees for additional services you have not yet paid for, such as laundry, phone calls, liquors from the mini-fridge, et al.

But since the statement you are asking about is in the section about *children and extra beds,* it probably means: *here are our rules about these things; we will charge you extra if you break them.* Meaning if you try to stick eight adults in a room meant for two, or you have six children and not two,  you will be expected to pay extra.

Edit for ColleenV's point:
Hi. I looked up a room for two nights in a hotel I am marginally familiar with. I see the webpage price. Near that is a 15% tax not included text. I went to actually reserve the room and it seems there are no "hidden fees," just the original price from the first page and the 15% tax added in:

```
>Room $458
TAX (15%) included $68.70
Today you'll pay $0
You'll pay at stay $526.70
```

Your booking includes:

```
- Free WiFi
- FREE cancellation
```

Total Price
    $526.70
(for 2 guests and 2 nights)

So I think that covers it. The website looks pretty on the up and up. But before I gave them any Personal Information, I would double check.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your concern got addressed through other answers posted here. However, I'd like to mention a very simple rule in regards to your a part of your grammar usage. (though there are other things, I'm sure I cannot go deep enough to explain them, so I prefer suggesting just one edit for now)
[image]

PS- I'm sorry if my answer is in any way against the community guidelines.
EDIT-
For instance, your sentence

> I think total cost mean everything

should   be

> I think total cost means everything.

Comment: This is quite true; but it is not an answer to the question. It would be more valuable to the poster as a sentence pointing out the precise error in the post.

Comment: @StoneyB Sure! As I mentioned in the first part of my answer, I assumed his doubt got clarified. I wanted to point out at something that I felt is equally important. Thanks for your comment though. :)